# how to set up a custom Navigation header in react native using shoutem/ui and exponent

Tags: react-native, exponent, shoutem

I'm using exponent and shoutem/ui on a project.

Here's exponent's built in navigation

https://github.com/exponent/ex-navigation

And I am trying to figure out how to customize the navbar with a search box and a filter dropdown using shoutem/ui.

https://github.com/shoutem/ui/tree/develop/navigation

Are they 2 mutually exclusive navigation bar implementations and I just have to pick one?

If so, I'm assuming I should use exponent's built in ex-navigation - but I'm not sure how to do things like set the font and add input boxes to it.

Do I add the buttons to a property in the navigationBar props?, e.g.:

```
 static route = {
    navigationBar: {
      visible: true,
      title: 'Join a Game',
      renderTitle: () => ( <Title>TITLE</Title> ),
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

We've updated documentation on our `NavBar` component, which you can see [here](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/components/navigation-bar). BTW, if you'll have problems using Shoutem UI toolkit with Exponent, see [this](https://github.com/shoutem/ui/tree/develop/examples/create-react-native-app) example.